# MATLAB - exponential fucntion not solving

Tags: matlab, math, exponential

Trying to solve for p in the equation below (eqn), Matlab is taking forever to solve it so im unsure how to optimize or if a better solve function exists. It can plot it easy enough, just solving for any value of p is impossible it seems.

```
A_1 = 0.1044;
R_1 = 84.0038;
A_2 = 0.02667;
R_2 = 118.4852;
h_max_2 = 1.889;
q_s = 0.08;
a = 1/(A_2*R_2);
b = 1/(A_1*R_1);
c = 1/(A_1*A_2*R_1);

syms p
eqn = h_max_2 == q_s*c*1/(a*b)*(1+1/(a-b)*(b*exp(-a*p)-a*exp(-b*p)));
time_until = solve(eqn_2,p)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about moving `h_max_2` over to the other side and find when the equation is zero? This can be solved with a simple call to `fzero`.

```
eqn = @(p) q_s*c*1/(a*b)*(1+1/(a-b)*(b*exp(-a*p)-a*exp(-b*p))) - h_max_2;
time_until = fzero(eqn, 0)
time_until = -2.7137
```

Alternatively, if you want a solution with a positive `p`, try using an initial guess of for instance `p0 = 10`.

```
time_until = fzero(eqn, 10)
time_until = 4.4923

eqn(time_until)
ans = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the last line of your code, there is no `eqn_2` variable, so I assume this is supposed to be `eqn`.  Otherwise, if you do have a `eqn_2` in your workspace, you could be trying to solve a very different function.

What version of MATLAB are you using?  Your code executed for me in less than 0.1 seconds on R2021a.  It did give the message `Warning:  Unable to solve symbolically. Returning a numeric solution using vpasolve.` and so your last line should probably be modified to be:  `time_until = vpasolve(eqn,p);`.  If your version of MATLAB doesn't automatically jump to `vpasolve`, that might explain what you are seeing.

For more complicated functions, you may get faster results by using `simplify` on your equation before solving, but in this case there was no time difference for me since it was already so fast.

The solution by @stewie-griffin where you rearrange to solve for when the function is zero is likely a better and faster way to do this in general, but I wanted to attempt to address the issues with the approach you tried.